# Rescaling set that intersects each perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

Suppose $D\subset\Bbb R$ such that $D\cap P\neq\emptyset$ for each nonempty perfect set $P\subset\Bbb R.$ Notice that $D$ need not to be a Bernstein set. Clearly, $D$ intersects each perfect set in continuum many points.

> Is $r D\cap P\neq\emptyset$ for every nonempty perfect set $P$ and $0\neq r\in\Bbb R$? $rD$ means rescaling $D$ by $r$.

I know rescaling the perfect set is still the perfect set. Any idea?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Adayah, I fixed , thank you

Comment: isn't $r D \cap P \neq \emptyset$ equivalent to $D \cap \frac 1 r P \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @Targon, I forgot about that. you are right. But $D\cap\bigcap_{0\neq r\in\Bbb R} \frac{1}{r} P$ might emptyset.

Comment: @00GB. What does $\bigcap_{0\ne r\in\Bbb R}\frac {1}{r}P$ have to do with your Q?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, since $r D\cap P= D\cap\frac{1}{r} P.$ Right? Now each $\frac{1}{r} P$ is a perfect set for $r\neq 0$. Fix a perfect set $P$ and consider $\bigcap_{r\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{r} P$. Question, $D\cap \bigcap_{r\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{r} P$ might emptyset. Right?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, did you see my last comment ?

Comment: If $P=[1,2]$ then $P\cap \frac {1}{3}P$ is empty. This is unrelated to your posted Q.  I think you are mixing up $\forall P\,\forall r\ne 0\,(P\cap rD\ne\emptyset)$ with $\cap_{r\ne 0}(P\cap rD\ne\emptyset).$ There exists $D$ meeting the conditions of your post with $0\ne D$ and $\forall x\in D\,(2x\not\in D)$, hence  $\cap_{r\ne 0}(P\cap rD)\subset (D\cap 2D)=\emptyset.$ We can even have $\forall q,q'\in \Bbb Q\, (q\ne 0 \ne q'\ne q\implies qD\cap q'D=\emptyset).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Thank you for your time. If I got your idea right $\bigcap_{r\neq 0}(P\cap r D)=\emptyset$ in most of the cases. Right?

Comment: Reread the last comment by @DanielWainfleet, especially the sentence that begins "I think you are mixing up ..."  Once you stop mixing those things up, the solution of your problem should be clear.